# react native: run spinner until ListView rendering

Tags: firebase, react-native, promise, firebase-realtime-database

in my app I pull data from Firebase and render them in a ListView. I want that the spinner will run until the entire list will appear.

I added the a view with a conditions that show if the state.loading is 'true', but if I change it in `componentDidMount` function does not work because the list is not yet displayed

Here is my code:

```
module.exports = React.createClass({
 getInitialState() {
return({
  loading: false,
  displayName: '',
  title: '',
  dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows([{
    title: '',
    author: ''
  }])
  })
},

componentDidMount() {
let user = firebaseApp.auth().currentUser;

if (!user.displayName) {
  this.props.navigator.push({
    name: 'chooseName'
  })
} else {
  // proceed normally with application
  this.setState({
    displayName: user.displayName
  })

  this.listenForItems(topicsRef);
 }

},

 listenForItems(ref) {
   ref.on('value', (snap) => {
  let topics = [];
  snap.forEach(topic => {
    topics.push({
      title: topic.val().title,
      author: topic.val().author,
        key: topic.key
    })
   })
  this.setState({dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(topics)});
   })
  },

  signOut() {
// sign out the user
firebaseApp.auth().signOut()
  .then(() => {
    // Sign out successful
    this.props.navigator.popToTop();
  }, (error) => {
    console.log(error);
  })
},

details(data) {
this.props.navigator.push({
  name: 'topicDetail',
  displayName: this.state.displayName,

  title: data.title,
  author: data.author,

  row_uid: data.key
})
},

 renderRow(rowData) {
return (
  <TouchableOpacity style={styles.row}
    onPress={() => this.details(rowData)}
  >
    <Text style={styles.rowTitle}>
      {rowData.title}
    </Text>
    <Text>
      {rowData.author}
    </Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
)

},

addTopic() {
topicsRef.push({
  title: this.state.title,
  author: this.state.displayName
})
},

render() {
if (this.state.loading) {
  return (
    <Container style={styles.containerSignIn}>
     <Content>
         <Spinner />

     </Content>
 </Container>);
}
return (
  <View style={styles.flexContainer}>
    <View style={styles.header}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => this.signOut()}
      >
        <Text style={styles.link}>
          Sign out
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <Text style={styles.title}>
        {this.state.displayName}
      </Text>
    </View>
    <View style={styles.body}>
      <TextInput
        placeholder='Something on your mind?'
        style={styles.input}
        onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({title: text})}
        onEndEditing={() => this.addTopic()}
      />
      <ListView
        style={styles.list}
        enableEmptySections={true}
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        renderRow={(rowData) => this.renderRow(rowData)}
      />
    </View>
  </View>
  )
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your Spinner component works.

Due to possible issues in your react lifecycle what I can recommend in the first run:

1.) if you want your Spinner to be active when your View shows up, set state.loading to true when defining your initialState.

```
getInitialState() {
    return({
        loading: true,
        ...
    })
}
```

2.) change the loading state in the (success) Promise callback of your firebase request and NOT in componentDidMount().

```
listenForItems(ref) {
    ref.on('value', (snap) => {
        ...
        this.setState({
            loading: false,
            dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(topics)
        });
    })
}
```

Hope that helps.